# how do i extract cells from multiple spreadsheets all with same format into new master file

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have 300 excel files each with the exact same format - 4 worksheets in each file with same column/row headers. I am trying to extract information from select cells of each of these 4 worksheets (for example, from cell D26 in worksheet A, from cell D62 in worksheet B, etc) from all 300 excel files and put that data into a new master excel file that contains the information from each of the 300 excel files. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes. Yes it will be easier if you can elaborate on what programming language you can use. VBA, WSH, powershell ... or do not care how.

Answer (score 0):

There is some really nice code posted [here](https://sites.google.com/a/madrocketscientist.com/jerrybeaucaires-excelassistant/merge-functions/consolidate-wbs-to-one-sheet) that should do what you want with a few tweaks.

Gordon

Some changes will need to be made which is nicely commented.  These rows get all the data from column A in the workbook and copy it to the master sheet.

```
LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row  'Find last row
Range("A1:A" & LR).EntireRow.Copy .Range("A" & NR)
```

Instead you will need to loop through the worksheets and set the ranges you want copy with something like this.

```
wbData.sheets(1).range("A2:A26").copy .Range("A" & NR)
NR = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
wbData.sheets(2).range("A2:A62").copy .Range("A" & NR)
NR = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
...
```